# Unable to Intercept Bot Response in Azure Bot Framework

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, chatbot

I want to intercept all the messages exchanged between user and bot. PFB code that I have used to intercept. I am using Bot Diaolog framework for webchat. Here the issue is I am not able to extract values from activities object which contains messages sent from bot to user.

```
adapter.use(async (turnContext, next) => {
// pre-processing of the current incoming activity
console.log("adapture use::turnContext::" + turnContext.activity.text);


// hook up a handler to process any outgoing activities sent during this turn
turnContext.onSendActivities(async (sendContext, activities, nextSend) => {
    // pre-processing of outgoing activities
    await nextSend();
    console.log("adapture use::activities::POST##::" + flat.stringify(activities));
    // post-processing outgoing activities
});

await next();

// post-processing of the current incoming activity 
console.log(`Processing activity ${turnContext.activity.id} finishing. `);
```

});

Comment: To update an existing message, pass a new Activity object with the existing activity ID to the updateActivity method of the TurnContext object : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/update-and-delete-bot-messages?tabs=typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the bot's responses, you can update the bot.js file (i.e. the file with the activity handlers defined) to something like the below.

In short, the `onSendActivities()` method keeps an array of the activities that have been passed in. You can cycle thru the activities pushing them into an array and then acting on a particular one. Or, react as each arrives. Further below are examples of each output.

```js
const { ActivityHandler, MessageFactory } = require('botbuilder');

class EchoBot extends ActivityHandler {
    constructor() {
        super();

        [...]

        const transcript = [];
        this.onTurn(async (context, next1) => {
            let responses = {};

            logActivity(transcript, cloneActivity(context.activity));

            context.onSendActivities(async (ctx, activities, next2) => {
                responses = await next2();
                activities.forEach((a) => logActivity(transcript, cloneActivity(a)));
                console.log('TRANSCRIPT ', activities);
                return responses;
            });

            await next1();
        });
    }
}

const logActivity = (transcript, activity) => {
    if (!activity.timestamp) {
        activity.timestamp = new Date();
    }
    transcript.push(activity);
};

const cloneActivity = (activity) => {
    return Object.assign({}, activity);
};

module.exports.EchoBot = EchoBot;
```

**Logging the `transcript` array:** Shows the list of activities.

```js
[
  {
    type: 'conversationUpdate',
    id: '1hEUP37Da8S',
    timestamp: 2021-09-07T23:01:04.910Z,
    serviceUrl: 'https://directline.botframework.com/',
    channelId: 'directline',
    from: { id: 'dl_16310556645490.nc93iu9jr1' },
    conversation: { id: '5JgOxxxxxxxxxxxxv6sw-g' },
    recipient: { id: 'somebot@QaeuoeEamLg', name: 'Some Bot' },
    membersAdded: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    rawTimestamp: '2021-09-07T23:01:04.9109865Z',
    callerId: 'urn:botframework:azure'
  },
  {
    type: 'message',
    text: 'Hello and welcome!',
    inputHint: 'acceptingInput',
    speak: 'Hello and welcome!',
    channelId: 'directline',
    locale: undefined,
    serviceUrl: 'https://directline.botframework.com/',
    conversation: { id: '5JgOxxxxxxxxxxxxv6sw-g' },
    from: { id: 'somebot@QaeuoeEamLg', name: 'Some Bot' },
    recipient: { id: 'dl_16310556645490.nc93iu9jr1' },
    timestamp: 2021-09-07T23:01:06.547Z
  },
  {
    type: 'message',
    id: '5JgOxxxxxxxxxxxxv6sw-g|0000001',
    timestamp: 2021-09-07T23:01:08.704Z,
    localTimestamp: 2021-09-07T23:01:08.527Z,
    localTimezone: 'America/Los_Angeles',
    serviceUrl: 'https://directline.botframework.com/',
    channelId: 'directline',
    from: { id: 'dl_16310556645490.nc93iu9jr1', name: '' },
    conversation: { id: '5JgOxxxxxxxxxxxxv6sw-g' },
    recipient: { id: 'somebot@QaeuoeEamLg', name: 'Some Bot' },
    textFormat: 'plain',
    locale: 'en-US',
    text: 'Hi',
    entities: [ [Object] ],
    channelData: {
      clientActivityID: '1631055668527tzwhm47a4qd',
      clientTimestamp: '2021-09-07T23:01:08.527Z'
    },
    rawTimestamp: '2021-09-07T23:01:08.704318Z',
    rawLocalTimestamp: '2021-09-07T16:01:08.527-07:00',
    callerId: 'urn:botframework:azure'
  },
  {
    type: 'message',
    text: 'Echo: Hi',
    inputHint: 'acceptingInput',
    speak: 'Echo: Hi',
    channelId: 'directline',
    locale: 'en-US',
    serviceUrl: 'https://directline.botframework.com/',
    conversation: { id: '5JgOxxxxxxxxxxxxv6sw-g' },
    from: { id: 'somebot@QaeuoeEamLg', name: 'Some Bot' },
    recipient: { id: 'dl_16310556645490.nc93iu9jr1', name: '' },
    replyToId: '5JgOxxxxxxxxxxxxv6sw-g|0000001',
    timestamp: 2021-09-07T23:01:09.147Z
  }
]
```

**Logging `activities` only:** Shows the last item to have passed thru from either the bot or user.

```js
[
  {
    type: 'message',
    text: 'Echo: Hi',
    inputHint: 'acceptingInput',
    speak: 'Echo: Hi',
    channelId: 'directline',
    locale: 'en-US',
    serviceUrl: 'https://directline.botframework.com/',
    conversation: { id: 'AURKxxxxxxxxxJHpO-f' },
    from: { id: 'somebot@QaeuoeEamLg', name: 'Some Bot' },
    recipient: { id: 'dl_16310605730140.3nrm4evq6um', name: '' },
    replyToId: 'AURKxxxxxxxxxJHpO-f|0000001'
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you @steven-kanberg for this solution. This is what I was looking for .

Answer (score -1):

Thank you [Rajeesh Menoth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2890048/rajeesh-menoth). Posting your suggestions as an answer to help other community members.

For updating existing message we can pass `NewActivityObject` with the existing activity ID to the `UpdateActivity` method of the `TurnContext` Object

Below is the sample to pass new object ID

```
const newActivity = MessageFactory.text('The new text for the activity');
newActivity.id = activityId;
await turnContext.updateActivity(newActivity);
```

To update the existing card on button selection, you can use `ReplyToId` of incoming activity.

```
const message = MessageFactory.attachment(card);
message.id = context.activity.replyToId;
await context.updateActivity(message);
```

For Further information check [Update Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/update-and-delete-bot-messages?tabs=typescript).

Comment: I  want to intercept messages exchange between User and Bot and don't want to update it so seeking solution for the same.

Comment: Additionally, Web Chat (which uses BotFramework Direct Line) does not support updating and/or deleting activities.